# Activity Monitor query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does the below query do? 
I got it on Activity Monitor, related to database restore.

```
SELECT  command,
    s.text,
    start_time,
    percent_complete, 
    CAST(((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate()))/3600) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%3600)/60 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ' sec' as running_time,
    CAST((estimated_completion_time/3600000) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %3600000)/60000 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go,
    DATEADD(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s

WHERE   r.command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG', 'BACKUP LOG')
```

Comment: it looks pretty clear by itself, it show you the running request on the server. It tries to show you the command where the below words are in (restore, backup, ...) You got that from the activity monitor with the profiler? It allows to the profiler to refresh columns with state, date and time

Comment: The problem is a can't restore my database before killing this process.

Comment: what is the error message when you try to restore? what do you kill? the process shown by this query or this process? (i understood this process, but to confirm :p)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as i have been doing this for the last few days, but  im sure sure it has something to do with database in use.

Answer (score 0):

This command will give you a status on a backup/restore process that is currently executing.  If you aren't the one running the script, then you need to figure how how and when it was run.  Perhaps it is creating a deadlock.

These sites may help you:

- [TSQL Backup Restore Progress](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/tsql_backup_restore_progress.aspx)
- [Check the progress of your backup/restore](http://scn.sap.com/community/sqlserver/blog/2013/10/08/do-you-need-to-check-the-progress-of-your-backuprestore)